# Azure DevOps build validation expiry option confusion

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In the main branch policies, I have configured Build validation policy to run a build pipeline whenever there is a PR raised against the main branch.

While configuring I observed that there are multiple options for build expiry

- Immediate
- After n hours
- Never

'Immediate' is easy to understand. But I have a confusion over 'After n hours' option.

For example: If I set the build expiry to 'After n hours' and raise a PR which has changes in file BaseClass.cs. When my PR related build pipeline is running, one of my team member changes in the BaseClass.cs got merged into the main branch. His change may have caused merge issues in Baseclass.cs.

After the build pipeline related to my PR is completed, because of the build policy to expire after n hours, pretty sure, I would be allowed to complete this PR.

So my question is whether ADO Git will fail merging this PR because of merge issues or my changes will overwrite my team member changes? If there are no merge issues, will it get completed?

I couldn't find clear doco on this in MS website hence asking for help here.

Comment: Build expiration has nothing to do with merging. Is your question about build expiration, or how PR merging works?

Comment: Hi Daniel, my question is, if we consider the above scenario mentioned in my question, when I press Complete button in the ADO PR UI, how code merge will be handled?

Answer (score 1):

When you raise a PR, the system builds a hypothetical merge commit of your work to the target branch. When this build is completed, the system sets its status on the PR. This build status is what actually meant when the docs talk about the expiration.

If another change is merged to the target branch by some other PR after the build of your PR is done, there can be different outcomes:

- your PR can't be merged because of the merge conflicts
- your PR can be merged (no conflicts), but the result doesn't build
- your PR can be merged (no conflicts), and the result of that merge builds just fine

Case #1 is the simplest and the most obvious - you simply can't merge your PR without conflict resolution. Case #3 is also safe - the result still builds green. The trickiest one is case #2 - as a result, you can get a red target branch.

The option to expire the build status is an additional safeguard for case #2 above:

- if you set it to Immediate, then the build status expires immediately when the target branch is updated, and the system tries to create a new merge commit and runs the build. This is the safest option - you're always in the situation when the build on the merge commit is verified and up to date. However, it might be too heavy for active repositories.
- if you set it to Never, it means that it is entirely your responsibility to verify the PR still builds before merging it. It might be a good habit to always rebase your branch to the target one before merging - this way you'll also have an up-to-date build. However, this is a question of the coding practices in the team.
- Regarding the "After N hours" expiration option, the docs say: "This option is a compromise between always or never requiring a build when the protected branch updates." Like with any compromise, there are pros and cons. If you lean towards safety, consider `Immediate` expiration. If you want to reduce the load on your build system and developers in the team are mature enough to be responsible, you can consider `Never` expiration.

> So my question is whether ADO Git will fail merging this PR because of merge issues...

Yes, if there are merge conflicts, the system will always fail the merge. Your changes will not overwrite your teammate's changes which are already in the target branch.

> If there are no merge issues, will it get completed?

Yes, but as I mentioned above the resulting merge commit in the target branch might not build green (case #2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: "However, it might be too heavy for active repositories." - in particular, it seems to put an upper limit to the number of PRs that can possibly be approved in a single day. In a large project (e.g. 100+ developers, and 15+ minutes for a build, which means <= 96 PRs a day), this can become a severe problem.

Answer (score -2):

If there's a conflict, the merge will stop and ask for you to resolve conflicts. If there's no conflict, autocomplete will work, causing no issues in the code.